# Is there a function whose graph is contained in one quadrant of the coordinate plane?

Tags: graphing-functions, analytic-geometry

Is there a function whose graph is contained in one quadrant of the coordinate plane?

It should be related to maths and not physics.

Please give me the equation and if possible its picture.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ for $x\in [0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Hayden no i mean without any limits...for example using mod functions etc???

Comment: What do you mean "without any limits"?  Perhaps you should make it a little more clear precisely what you want, because it sounds like you want examples of functions from the non-negative reals to itself.

Comment: "Graph" is curve or function?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Well you know what i'm asking...just for a little curiosity!

Comment: $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks man... it worked!

Comment: You are welcome. The circle suggested in one of the answers is a nice familiar one.

Comment: @AndréNicolas ya but it should be a valid function since according to the vertical line test, a circle is not a function

Comment: @AndréNicolas BTW can you also please suggest an increasing function of the same type?

Comment: Just found out the easiest one... $\sqrt{y}$ = $\sqrt{x}$

Comment: That is a nice one, a ray (half-line).

Answer (score 2):

The upper (or lower) half of any circle with center in the first quadrant and radius < distance center-axes, like
$$y = 2 + \sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}.$$

Comment: Well it should be a valid function since according to the vertical line test, a circle is not a function.

Comment: @NeilRoy, take the upper half.

Answer (score 2):

How about $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$?